# hyperlink passing value into url

Tags: javascript, mongodb, url, hyperlink

I am trying to create a hyperlink for a online project. 
which i did like so ...

```
            '<a href="#/app/tabs/tours/"> Go to Tour info </a>' +
            '</p>';
```

I am have a value called ._id which has an auto generated number like 5556528. 
Every time i try and add ._id the url ends up like
www.blahblah.com/#/app/tabs/tours/._id

I need the hyperlink the have the randomly generated number at the end of it too look like

```
www.blahblah.com/#/app/tabs/tours/5556528
```

How would I change the hyperlink to do so??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector("a"),
    href   = anchor.getAttribute("href"),
    output = document.querySelector(".output"),
    button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", changeURL);

function changeURL() {
  anchor.setAttribute("href", href + getRandomNumber());
  output.innerHTML = anchor.getAttribute("href");
}

// return 5 digit number
function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#/app/tabs/tours/"> Go to Tour info </a>
<p class="output"></p>
<button>Change URL</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another common approach for random numbers is to use the time from the browser:

```
var date = new Date();

var str = '<a href="#/app/tabs/tours/'+date+'"> Go to Tour info </a>' +
        '</p>';
```